# SSLError when AWS lambda downloads from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate, boto3

I've created a Python lambda function that downloads a file from S3 bucket. I gave this lambda the role that allows this. And this code works fine locally. But when executed on AWS Lambda it returns with an error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: SSLError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 104, in downloadNewImage
s3_client.download_file(bucketName, imagePath, dest_pathname)
...
File "/var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Changing how I create `s3_client` from:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
```

to this:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', verify=False)
```

solved the problem. But now I see a lot of warnings in the log:

> /var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:768: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html

Why there is such an error in the AWS Lambda environment? And how to fix it properly?

Comment: Generally, it is caused by ca file not found. Not sure if this file is available on AWS lambda.

Comment: Can you try setting the region when creating the s3 client? `s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')`

Comment: @NinadGaikwad I did `s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1')` it still runs fine locally, but `download_file` still returns an error on AWS: `module initialization error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: What do you mean it works fine locally?

Comment: For development purposes I use `python-lambda`. It allows to run lambda code locally before deploying it to the cloud. So, `lambda invoke` works same way with this change.

Comment: I have seen this error when including the package "requests" into the python runtime. It is utterly undiagnosable based on the error. Could this be the problem you are hitting?